# How to get OpenID Connect to work using client certificate rather than secret (PHP)?

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm a newbie to OIDC, and am deploying an SSO application. Everything works well while using a client secret with the code below, but my company's Azure AD/Entra configuration requires use of a client certificate (rather than secret) when using mobile devices.

I've generated a key pair using openssl and uploaded the public key to the Azure portal, confirmed that the thumbprint is correct. However I can't figure out how to feed the private key into my code. Can someone please help?

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;
$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient('*url*', '*clientid*', null);
$oidc->setTokenEndpointAuthMethodsSupported(['private_key_jwt']);
$oidc->authenticate();
print_r($oidc->requestUserInfo());
```

Comment: I'm not a specialist ether, but isn't the client certificate supposed to be installed on the mobile device?

Comment: @Olivier I believe the public key is added to the Azure portal and private key is embedded into the PHP code. So this serves as a check that the OIDC client is authorized to use the Azure AD endpoint. If the private key is supposed to be transferred from the client to the mobile device (which seems like a security risk), then advice on implementing this is also appreciated. The goal is to be able to auth using a client certificate rater than a client secret.

Comment: *"The goal is to be able to auth..."* To auth who? The server which runs PHP? Or the final user who accesses the web app through their mobile device?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, the final user needs to be authenticated by Azure, and this needs to be communicated to the PHP server (OIDC client).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching and combining various resources, I think I found an answer. Posting here for others who may have the same question.

Key points:

1. Enable 'private_key_jwt' as a supported Auth method using `$oidc->setTokenEndpointAuthMethodsSupported()`
2. Write a custom function that creates a standard JWT using the client information, signed by the private key. Bind this to $oidc using `$oidc->setPrivateKeyJwtGenerator()`
3. The public certificate thumbprint generated by Azure/OpenSSL is a hex string (like AB12C2D5FF...)- this needs to be converted into binary and then base64 encoded, added to the JWT header as the 'x5t' parameter: `$headers['x5t'] = \base64_encode(\hex2bin('*public_key_thumbprint*'))`

PHP OIDC Client Code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

$clientId = '*clientId*';
$oidc = new OpenIDConnectClient('*url*', $clientId, null);
$oidc->setTokenEndpointAuthMethodsSupported(['private_key_jwt']);
$oidc->setPrivateKeyJwtGenerator(function (string $token_endpoint) {
    global $clientId;
    $key = \file_get_contents('*private_key_file*');
    $headers = [
        'typ' => 'JWT',
        'alg' => 'RS256',
        'x5t' => \base64_encode(\hex2bin('*public_cert_thumbprint*')),
    ];
    $payload = [
        'iss' => $clientId,
        'sub' => $clientId,
        'aud' => $token_endpoint,
        'jti' => \base64_encode(\random_bytes(16)),
        'exp' => \time() + 300,
    ];
    openssl_sign(
        base64UrlEncode(json_encode($headers)) . "." . base64UrlEncode(json_encode($payload)),
        $signature,
        $key,
        "sha256WithRSAEncryption"
    );
    $jwt = base64UrlEncode(json_encode($headers)) . "." . base64UrlEncode(json_encode($payload)) . "." . base64UrlEncode($signature);

    return $jwt;
});
$oidc->authenticate();
print_r($oidc->requestUserInfo());

function base64UrlEncode(string $text): string
{
    return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($text), '+/', '-_'), '=');
}
`
```

Comment: Thanks, working on this too. JumboJett OIDC Example 10 says just "# TODO: what ever is necessary", so it's very helpful to show what is necessary! I found this page pretty helpful: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/build-self-signed-jwt/js/main/

Comment: How do you get the `public_cert_thumbprint`? Is this meant to be a certificate fingerprint?

Comment: @MatejSvajger yes. `openssl x509 -in cert.crt -noout -fingerprint` (ref https://www.jvt.me/posts/2019/04/03/openssl-fingerprint-x509-pem/)